# UITextFieldDelegate crash (exc_bad_access)

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

Looks like I have a problem with `UITextFieldDelegate`.

I just created a view controller that responds to `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, and easily added the field to the xib, then set delegate field...you know.

But when I trying to press the field (to start editing, the program crashes).

Same thing happens when I trying to create field programmatically.

Here is call stack:

[image]

Here is full code:

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TopBar : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITextField * field_top;
}
```

**.m**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldBeginEditing");
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:220.0f/255.0f green:220.0f/255.0f blue:220.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing");
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldEndEditing");
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidEndEditing");
}
```

Delegate is set by IB.

Error screenshot:

[image]

Any help please.

Comment: Have you implemented the delegate methods ? If so, could you show them ?

Comment: Please can you share all your code.

Comment: The stack doesn't help much. Can you post your code showing the delegate methods for UITextField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
The solution is ti also use addChildViewConroller, not only addSubview.
Hope it will help to someone...

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have this in your .h

```
@interface TopBar : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

}

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *field_top;
```

and remove from the `@interface`

```
IBOutlet UITextField * field_top;
```

It sounds like your field_top is being released and you're trying to access it later, thats why it's crashing.

Comment: You know, I tried ti do as you said, but it still crashes.
Can't understand what's going on, made that many times. Maybe this is because parent view is in scrollview?...dunno =(

Comment: How are you accessing field_top ? Where are you using it ? What is the crash message ?

Comment: Whats the crash message in the debugger ?

Comment: There is no any messages...or I dunno how to see them. I posted screenshot below..

Comment: Does it crash after you tap something ?

Comment: Oh yes, of course! Sorry, ma bad, I not written about it. App crashes when I trying to tap the text field.